# How to detect free space between two detected windows

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

**I used YOLOv3 to detect windows on the building. Each window shows with a bounding box around, also I extracted coordinates of each window [top_left, bottom_left, top_right, bottom_right]. now I want to find free space[wall] between all the windows. I put the coordinates of each window in a Dict.
when I set the values manually it works for each window for instance:**

```
p1 = points_list[0][2] # top_left window1
p2 = points_list[1][1] # bottom_left window2
cv2.rectangle(img, p1, p2, (255, 0, 255), -1)
```

**, but how can I make it automatically to find walls.**
Here is [my first output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQw6v.png), the detected wall shows by pink color.
here also I have added a sample of my code.

```
def bb_to_rect(x, y, w, h):
    top_left = (x, y)
    top_right = (x + w, y)
    bottom_left = (x, y + h)
    bottom_right = (x + w, y + h)
return top_left, bottom_left, top_right, bottom_right

def draw_bounding_box(img, font, boxes, confidences, colors):

    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, CONF_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)
    points_list={}
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        if i in indices:

           (x, y, w, h) = boxes[i]
           label = "{}:{:.2f}%".format(classes[class_ids[i]], confidences[i] * 100)
           color = colors[class_ids[i]]
           cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
           cv2.putText(img, str(i), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX,
                      .5, (255, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

           top_left, bottom_left, top_right, bottom_right = bb_to_rect(x, y, w, h)
           points_list[count] = [top_left, bottom_left, top_right, bottom_right]
           count += 1

           cv2.circle(img, (x + w, y), 3, (50, 100, 0), -1) # top Right
           cv2.circle(img, (x + w, y + h), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1) # bottom Right
           cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 100), -1)  # top left
           cv2.circle(img, (x, y + h), 3, (255, 0, 255), -1)  # bottom left

return img, points_list

if __name__ == "__main__":

     net, output_layers, colors, classes = load_yolo_model()
     img, height, width = load_img(IMAGES_PATH)

     outs = create_blob(img, net, output_layers)
     boxes, class_ids, confidences, centroids = detect_obj(outs, height, width, img)

     img, points_list = draw_bounding_box(img, FONT, boxes, confidences, colors)

     p1 = points_list[0][2] # window0 to window1
     p2 = points_list[1][1]

     p2_1 = points_list[1][2] # window1 to window2
     p2_2 = points_list[2][1]

     p3_1 = points_list[3][2] # window3 to window5
     p5_2 = points_list[5][1]

     cv2.rectangle(img, p1, p2, (255, 0, 255), -1)
     cv2.rectangle(img, p2_1, p2_2, (255, 0, 255), -1)
     cv2.rectangle(img, p3_1, p5_2, (255, 0, 255), -1)
     cv2.imshow('out', img)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Also if you see the photo you will see the windows detected randomly and the Id number for each window does not order. How can I solve this problem? thanks in advance for helping:)

Comment: draw your detected windows bounding boxes filled white on a black image. the remaining black areas are free space

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Image Segmentation to find the objects on wall? then with a simple trick like finding the countors you can measure the distance between the objects like windows as you said.

**2nd trick:**
I've got another easy way which may help you:
first of all, find the edges using canny edg detection, the with dilate function fill the middle space of vertical edges between windows then by **Hough Line Detection** you can find the vertical lines of windows, and get **the distance** between the y axis of vertical lines of the wall.

Comment: Thank you for replying. no, I didn't try image segmentation yet. it could be a good idea. about 2nd trick, the owner wants to use deep learning techniques. but I can test this method as well to see the performance might it work better. Tnx